# Automating selecting dropdown option thats Javascript

Tags: java, javascript, selenium

I am trying to select a value from a dropdown menu but most of the page is Javascript (using Document.write).

Is it possible to still reference these elements as if they were done in HTML? I have tried the conventional way but that didnt seem to work.

IE. ( selenium.select("name=entitySelect", "value=02"); )

```
document.write("<td width='50px' class='topnavi_text'>" + "Select &nbsp;</td>" + 
    "<td><select name='entitySelect' class='textfieldfontwithoutwidth2' onChange='changeEntity()'>");
```

There is no ID to actually reference either.

Comment: Make sure you have the `value` attribute in the selected option and if not try with the `label=02` (the visible text) option selector instead of value.

Comment: I tried doing a String[] elements = selenium.getSelectOptions("name=entitySelect"); and the array is empty. So actually referencing is the problem

Comment: Are you sure you are running this selenium code after the element has been created?

Comment: Yes, I have selenium.open then selenium.waitForPageToLoad("30000"); before trying to do the selection

Comment: And also there must be at least one option in the `select`.

Comment: I have 2, i need to select the second one

Comment: Try the following in your code `selenium.getEval("window.document.select.length;");`. It will return the number of `select tags` and it will be done using javascript. Just try printing the returned value.